# Ubuntu 18.04 not showing low battery warning

Tags: 18.04, power-management, battery, notification

This question might seem very basic. I am new to Ubuntu (recently moved from Windows).
I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and it doesn't show warning when my battery is low, instead laptop automatically turns off. There is a battery icon that shows current status, but no warning message when battery gets low.

It would be great if I could find a way within Ubuntu options, if not then please suggest any any third party package.

Comment: I have the same issue, @arsalan. The device just shuts down, without a warning. The icon is there, but of course I'm not checking that all the time.

Comment: same for me, lost some work today

Comment: Related Unix Stack Exchange question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60778/how-can-i-get-an-alert-when-my-battery-is-about-to-die-in-linux-mint

Answer (score 1):

This article details how to use dconf editor to alter the low battery behaviors. You can see if somehow your settings are non-default or not to your liking.

- http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/07/change-battery-critical-low-action-ubuntu-18-04/